# Plupload - Resize image on upload, with a minimum height, and minimum width instead of maximum

Tags: javascript, php, image, plupload

I have a Plupload uploader running, which is making both a thumbnail and a large size image when uploading each image.

The thumbnail I need to make fit into a 150x150px box. I have some javascript that scales the image down, so that the smallest width or height of the image gets to be 150px, and the bigger one is hidden with overflow:hidden.

The problem is when I use the Plupload script for resizing, it only takes "maximum" sizes for width and height, meaning that if I have a image that have a 1:2 ratio, it would be resized to 75x150px.

Is there any way of making this work as minimum sizes?

This is how my thumbnail resize looks at the moment:

```
var uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();

uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function(up, file) {
  if('thumb' in file){
    up.settings.url = 'upload.php?dir=' + ($("#chosen_gallery :selected").val()) + '&subdir=thumbs',
    up.settings.resize = {width : 150, height : 150, quality : 60};
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that the best pick of a php lib for image resizing? I just need something simple, but if the library have a filter for resizing, so quality isn't lost, that would be a plus.

Comment: You would need to code it yourself but resizing is possible

Comment: Check: http://salman-w.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/crop-to-fit-image-using-aspphp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `crop:true` value on the resize settings object. Will scale to the shorter side, then crop the ends to match your specified width/height

Comment: make sure the image is larger on both dimensions, however, since uploading a smaller than the max dimensions will not get scaled up, and the developers have made no promises to add that in the next release either.